# PrestaShop no image available for thumbnail in backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have moved a shop from one server to another with the same domain name (switch dns with the new ip). Since the migration, the thumbnail in the description of products in back office are not displayed and I get the "no image available" instead. The images seem to be there but not displayed. The version is 1.5.6 and an upgrade to 1.6 doesn't change anyting. Any idea how to change it. I already tried to generate the thumbnail again and clear the smarty cache.

[image: screenshot of my backoffice]

Comment: I'm not familiar of Prestashop but i use it sometimes. It is a good ecommerce cms. You should look at `img/tmp` as far as i know backoffice images are should be there. I am not sure but cleaning that folder may be help.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after moving from one server to another.
The answer was to manually create a tmp folder inside the img folder, and chmod that, 777. (chmod img 777 also, I did, but not sure it's necessary).
The issue is that the program cannot create, or write images to that folder.